# Why my database do not get vars sent from mysql_query();?

Tags: php, mysql

My connection to database works properly, but when I Send some information it does not update.

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$mail = mysql_escape_string($_POST['mail1']);
$pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `usrs` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (`NULL`, `$name`, `$mail`, `$pass`)");
```

I use to check data tables by:

```
MariaDB [BattleShip]> SELECT * FROM usrs;
```

output from this:

> EMPTY set (0.00sec)

Comment: Are you sure your INSERT is working properly?

Comment: I didn't know you could connect to MariaDB using `mysql_`. Anyway, stop using `mysql_` functions because they are deprecated.

Comment: Your `INSERT` didn't work, it seems.  Check to see if there were any errors.  `$result = mysql_query(...);  if($result === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`.  P.S. You shouldn't be using `mysql_*` or concatenating variables into an SQL query.  Use MySQLi/PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: MariaDB is just a drop-in replacement for MySQL.  It uses the same APIs :-)

Comment: Don't use backticks to quote user input.

Comment: In fact, don't quote user input at all: switch to MySQLi or PDO and use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: SOLVED: auto_increment was not set; also problem was with backticks;

Comment: Why are you using backticks around `NULL`?

Answer (score -1):

If your id is auto increment, don't include this column in query
...and replace value quote by '

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `usrs` (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$mail', '$pass')");
```